# HDMI adapter supporting both DisplayPort and mini-DisplayPort

Tags: hdmi, display-port

We have a TV we want to connect to our array of laptops. The laptops have **DisplayPort** or **mini-DisplayPort** output while the TV has only **1 HDMI** output (alas).

So the obvious solution would be to have an HDMI extension cord M/M that is attached either to an HDMI/DisplayPort (F/M) adapter or an HDMI/mini-DisplayPort (F/M) adapter and you need to plug the adapter depending of your laptop output.

Users being users, they find it hard to switch to the correct adapter so we were wondering if there is an HDMI adapter that support both DisplayPort and mini-DisplayPort so the adapter would be always plugged to the extension cord.

My prior search on the internet seems to indicate such adapter do not exists so maybe there is another way to accomplish what we want.

I envisioned having an HDMI splitter to be able to work with two HDMI output (each plugged with a different adapter) but we are worried about losing signal quality. So we would like your opinion on how should we proceed and suggestions about components we should use.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be a little late, but I do know of one potential option. I couldn't find an adapter like what you describe (I was looking for the DisplayPort equivalent of [this](http://amzn.com/B00ESM3ZHG)), but they do make HDMI source switchers with automatic input select, for example [this one from A-Tech](http://amzn.com/B00NPHLDQA):

[image]

It has a select button but also will automatically select inputs if only one is connected.

Then, to one input, connect a DisplayPort -> HDMI conversion cable. To the other, connect a Mini DisplayPort -> HDMI cable. Leave the cable ends hanging out in the open for users to see, and let them pick.

Another thing you could do, although it might be slightly more complicated for users, is use a DisplayPort -> HDMI cable. Leave it exposed. Then get a [slim Mini DisplayPort -> Display Port adapter](http://amzn.com/B003YKX6K4) and tie it to the end of the cable with a little string. Users with mini DP can use it if they need it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even if it is late. I shall relay your inputs to the person in charge.